# Struggling to implement Row Level Security to my Power BI Report

Tags: security, powerbi, dax, row-level-security

I have a model, which includes two tables I need to filter on this RLS.

There is a financial hierarchy, which includes a column called 'Path', which is a path of different level ID's.
I have a User table, which includes a list of Emails of people who need access, and an 'Access ID'.
I need to ensure that the email is identified as the person trying to access the report, and then their Access ID needs to be looked up in the Path column in the hierarchy table, to see if that ID appears in the Path, and they'll be given access to those rows.

If anyone can help that would be great.

This is my first time implementing any RLS, and it seems quite a complicated one to start with, so tried multiple pieces of code from GPT and Bard but no luck so far.

Comment: Removed the "accessibility" tag, as the question has nothing to do with accessibility as defined by tag description.